# Eine gute Eselsbrücke für die Wochentage

Tags: mnemonic

Man hat mich nach einer guten Eselsbrücke, um sich Wochentage zu merken, gefragt. Da ich selbst keine kenne, dachte ich, ich frage Euch.

Bis jetzt habe ich die zwei hier gefunden, <strike>aber eine verstehe ich nicht</strike> muddy meadow = nasse Wiese:

> http://erdenkinder.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/eselsbrucken/
>
> > Kommt die Jüngere zu mir und sagt: “Ich merke mir die Wochentage immer
> >     mit der feuchten Wiese! Sowas wie ein Moor, oder wie heisst das?”
> >     “Hmm.. was tust du?” “Ja, mit der feuchten Wiese.” “Aha..”, jetzt
> >     arbeitet es bei mir – ich versuche mir vorzustellen was so eine
> >     feuchte Wiese oder ein Moor mit den Wochentagen zu tun haben könnte…
> >     habe aber keine wirklich sinnvolle Idee. “Wie kommt das? Wie kommst du
> >     darauf?” “Ja, ganz einfach: MoDiMiDo FrSaSo!” “Ah… ja, das sind die
> >     Abkürzungen der Wochentage – aber was haben denn die mit einer
> >     feuchten Wiese zu tun?” “Ja, eben: ModiMido FrSaSo, nasse Wiese
> >     FrSaSo!” Nachdem sie es mir noch ein bis zwei mal, jedesmal ein wenig
> >     deutlicher, gesagt hat, ist dann auch bei mir der Groschen gefallen.
> >     “Ja”, meinte Yana, “ganz einfach: modi mido, muddy meadow, nasse
> >     Wiese, Fr Sa So!”

Und die andere wäre, meiner Meinung nach, nicht so intuitiv für Ausländer (wobei vielleicht täusche ich mich):

> http://www.focus.de/schule/lernen/lernhilfen/tid-13592/mnemotechnik-koerperroute-technik_aid_377801.html
>
> > "Erstklässler sollen sich die Wochentage in richtiger Reihenfolge von
> >     Montag bis Sonntag merken. Man stelle sich vor, der Mond liegt auf den
> >     Schuhen (Montag), auf dem Knie sitzt ein Diener (Dienstag), in der
> >     Hosentasche liegt ein in der Mitte geteiltes Stoffstück (Mittwoch). Am
> >     Gesäß donnert es auf der Toilette (Donnerstag), der Bauchnabel ist
> >     frei (Freitag), Sand rieselt auf die Brust (Samstag), die Sonne
> >     scheint auf den Kopf (Sonntag)"

Comment: Man verbindet Tage oft mit dem, was man regelmäßig an dem Tag macht. Gestern war ich z.B. davon überzeugt, dass schon Dienstag war, nur weil ich ausnahmsweise mal montags im Fitnessstudio war. - Am besten funktioniert das also, in dem man sich selbst die Eselsbrücke aufbaut. Jedem Tag ordnet man eine Tätigkeit oder ähnliches zu, die eben für diesen Tag eindeutig ist. Und dann muss man im Kopf nur noch den Ablauf der einzelnen Tätigkeiten durchgehen und hat die Tage in der richtigen Reihenfolge.

Comment: Vielleicht wird so ein Kinderlied helfen?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0zawwsQj_w

Answer (score 5):

Wie wäre es mit dem Sams der Augsburger Puppenkiste, ein Lied bleibt ja immer recht gut hängen.

> Montag kommt der Herr Mohn
>   Dienstag hab ich Dienst
>   Mittwoch ist Mitte der Woche
>   Donnerstag gibt es Donner
>   Freitag hab ich frei 
>   Samstag kommt das Sams
>   Sonntag scheint die Sonne

Comment: Ich habe ein selbst ausgedachtes Liedchen vorgeschlagen "MoDi-MiDo-Frei-SaSo" / "MoDi-MiDo-Frei-SaSo" / "MoDi-MiDo-Frei-SaSo" :)

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt, ich finde, alle diese Eselsbrücken sind schwieriger zu merken als die Wochentage selber ;-)

Comment: Die korrekte Quellenangabe wäre allerdings hier Paul Maar, dessen Bücher u.a. von der Augsburger Puppenkiste adaptiert wurden.

Comment: Mit Eselsbrücken ist das ja immer so eine Sache ;-) Beim einen wirken sie Wunder, beim andern sorgen sie für mehr Verwirrung als vorher.

Comment: Dass dieses Lied vom Samse ist, das halte ich für großen Mist. Denn käme es vom Samse her, würd es sich reimen, aber sehr.

Answer (score 4):

Wer soll denn die Wochentage lernen? Ein Kind mit Muttersprache Deutsch oder ein Ausländer, der die Tage in seiner Sprache schon kennt?

Ich frage, weil im Englischen Friday, Saturday, Sunday und Monday schon sehr ähnlich sind. Da muss man nur DiMiDo lernen. Das geht aber leichter in der 4er-Gruppe: MoDiMiDo. Die Anfangsbuchstaben bilden ein Muster (MDMD) und die ersten Vokale (oiio) – mal eine Wiederholung, mal eine Spiegelung.

> Morgens dirigiert Miss Dorit freizügig Samba-Songs.

Comment: Man kann sogar anstatt 'morgends' 'montags' verwenden, d.h. 'Montags dirigiert Miss Dorit freizügig Samba-Songs.'

Comment: @MurVotema: Man kann auch "Miss Donnerstag" verwenden - nur konterkariert das ja den eigentlichen Zweck der Übung: eine Gedächtnisstütze für den jeweiligen Tagesnamen zu liefern; man müsste 'montags' bereits kennen und hätte also keine Eselsbrücke nötig.

Comment: „Morgens“. _Oh, bei der Suche nach einer klärenden Seite habe ich das hier gefunden:_ http://www.willis-witze.de/Berufe-Witze/Frau-beim-Metzger-Ich-haette-gern-1-Pfun,witz-1153.html

Comment: Die Eselsbrücke gefällt mir übrigends (sic & grins) sehr gut!

Answer (score -2):

Man = Montag
das = Dienstag 
macht = Mittwoch 
doch = Donnerstag 
Freude = Freitag 
so = Samstag 
süss = Sonntag

Comment: _Man das macht doch Freunde so süß_? Was soll das bedeuten?

Comment: @Iris riddle :-)